# How do I find out which of 2 methods is faster?

Tags: go, profiling

I have 2 methods to trim the domain suffix from a subdomain and I'd like to find out which one is faster. How do I do that?

[2 string trimming methods](http://play.golang.org/p/DOw6a1e0S4)

Comment: @Leo This is Go not Java and I doubt OP is using [jgo](http://code.google.com/p/jgo/) :)

Comment: I think the blog post overemphasises the benefits of optimising for 10ns/op.

Comment: @nemo I am so sorry :-( let me fix that

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the builtin [benchmark capabilities](http://golang.org/pkg/testing/#hdr-Benchmarks) of [`go test`](http://golang.org/cmd/go/#hdr-Test_packages).

For example ([on play](http://play.golang.org/p/pK1dEs-oGT)):

```
import (
    "strings"
    "testing"
)


func BenchmarkStrip1(b *testing.B) {
    for br := 0; br < b.N; br++ {
        host := "subdomain.domain.tld"

        s := strings.Index(host, ".")
        _ = host[:s]
    }
}

func BenchmarkStrip2(b *testing.B) {
    for br := 0; br < b.N; br++ {
        host := "subdomain.domain.tld"

        strings.TrimSuffix(host, ".domain.tld")
    }
}
```

Store this code in `somename_test.go` and run `go test -test.bench='.*'`. For me this gives
the following output:

```
% go test -test.bench='.*'
testing: warning: no tests to run
PASS
BenchmarkStrip1 100000000           12.9 ns/op
BenchmarkStrip2 100000000           16.1 ns/op
ok      21614966    2.935s
```

The benchmark utility will [attempt to do a certain number of runs](http://code.google.com/p/go/source/browse/src/pkg/testing/benchmark.go?name=go1.2#175) until a meaningful time is
measured which is reflected in the output by the number `100000000`. The code was run 
`100000000` times and each operation in the loop took 12.9 ns and 16.1 ns respectively.
So you can conclude that the code in `BenchmarkStrip1` performed better.

Regardless of the outcome, it is often better to [profile your program](http://blog.golang.org/profiling-go-programs) to see where the
real bottleneck is instead of wasting your time with micro benchmarks like these.

I would also not recommend writing your own benchmarking as there are some factors you might
not consider such as [the garbage collector](http://code.google.com/p/go/source/browse/src/pkg/testing/benchmark.go?name=go1.2#113) and [running your samples long enough](http://code.google.com/p/go/source/browse/src/pkg/testing/benchmark.go?name=go1.2#191).

Comment: How do I increase the sample rate? I read the pprof article before but it seemed too complicated on first sight. It was always trying to curl an url and then said no such file or directory. http://pastebin.com/0Ff7DWP7

Comment: Well I'm going to accept the answer although I still don't know which of the 2 methods to trim a string is faster, but it's good enough for a general question/answer. If anyone has a better answer I'll gladly accept it. Trying time.Now() and .Sub() showed that the TrimSuffix() method was faster in the majority of cases. What's weird tho is that either method was up to 200ns faster/slower. Both started out at 250ns TrimSuffix() neared 70ns where [:s] was mostly ~130ns. Then they neared 70ns with an odd spike of ~250ns of TrimSuffix(). Idk how reliable time.Now() and Sub() is.

Comment: I'm sorry but I messed up the benchmark example. I forgot to execute the test as often as the benchmark tool demands (`b.N`). The sample rate of the benchmark tool is automatically determined so you can't modify it directly and it has nothing to do with pprof. I just meant that you should consider using profiling before wasting your time with micro benchmarks which most of the time do not solve the real problem in your code performance wise.